# Simulation tool to calculate microprocessor power consumption?

Tags: microcontroller, simulation, microprocessor

Are there any simulation tools to calculate microprocessor power consumption at the early brainstorming stage of development?

Comment: It depends so much on the particular device, support circuitry and the code that I don't believe there are any general purpose tools. Maybe you have a specific case you could mention to get some ideas on how to approach it for that case?

Comment: ok.actually, I am going to do one ieee project. so in that , I need to calculate power consumption of microprocessor using simulation tool. but  couldn't find any tool to measure it. give me  any tool name if any available.

Comment: But what microprocessor, are you designing your own in silicon? If not you're going to have to either rely on datasheet figures or measure it yourself.

Comment: ok tell me. is there any tool to calculate power consumption of any controller or microprocessor?

Comment: I'm still not clear if you're talking about something you're making yourself or something like say a PIC / AVR. If the latter last time I did it I used Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Atrenta spyglass is #2 behind Synopsys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There are no tools that I know of.  And if there were, they would be mostly useless.  There are just too many factors to consider that any tool would be wildly inaccurate.  If you do this at the very early stages of project conception, when most of your software has yet to be written, then your estimates could be 10x or more off!

The best that you can do is look at the microcontroller datasheet and estimate your max power consumption.  You could get a little deeper into it by also estimating how much time the MCU will be in sleep mode and factor that into it.  Much beyond that and you will not get much more accurate even though you spend a lot more time trying to estimate things.  Software tools will not help you much in this regard, even if they existed.

Comment: Nice Explanation dude. I got clear. because most of our academic project based on simulation. That's why I asked this question here. if I want to test it I have try by using datasheets. nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Current low power microprocessors have many operation modes with various power consumption levels in each mode. for example, the TI MSP430 (an ultra low power 16Bit MCU) has an active mode current of 180 to 270uA per MHz, at least 3 lower power modes with different power consumption in each mode, and that is without the peripherals. Taking all those parameters into account is quite a task, however, some vendors have tools to these simulations easier (Energy Micro have these integrated into their IDE).

It is much easier to get an evaluation board, add your application circuit and measure the current consumption at each mode.

Comment: what is the name of that simulation tool?

Comment: @user1664906  He didn't say there was a simulation tool.  He did say that Energy Micro has a tool for estimating power based on low power modes.  Google it.  He also said, "It is much easier to get an evaluation board... and measure the current..."

Comment: fine. Fine. got it.

Comment: @user1664906 - I think Dave Jones at EEVBlog has a video on an Energy Micro dev board and the IDE. You might find it useful to watch that - I seem to recall there being some cool stuff in the IDE to predict power consumption.

Comment: @OliGlaser-fine.it will useful to my project

Answer (score 1):

Yes, their are simulation tools for calculation of power. Orion 2.0 is an open source tool that is used to calculate power consumption of the On-chip Network of microprocessors. 
Also we can have simulation tools for designing of a customized system (platform) of any renowned processor, that are called Open Virtual Platforms.
Renowned processors include OpenRISC, MIPS, Intel, ARM, ARC, ALTERA and many more...

Comment: Altera and Intel are not a processors, those are companies. It would be better to cite specific cores supported by the simulator (I doubt it can calculate power consumption for ALL Intel chips).

Comment: """Renowned processors include OpenRISC, MIPS, Intel, ARM, ARC, ALTERA and many more..."""    Altera and Intel written in my paragraph means that the processor made by Altera and Intel are also suppored...

Answer (score 0):

Altera's supported processors that are supported by Imperas are:
Nios II S
Nios II F
It can simulate these processors in the form of single core, double core as well as many core...
And Heterogeneous configuration of processors are also supported.